# How do I make the database perform an index scan?

Tags: sql, indexing, database-scan

Simple question I think.  I want to do an index scan on a table but it's not doing it.  So I have a table with a unique clustered index on ID column and have 2 other columns, first_name and last_name.  The following was my query...

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE 'GUY'
```

I thought since I wasn't searching on the column with the index it should do it.

Why isn't it working and how do I make sure that I can get this to work every time I want it to?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You have an index into FIRST_NAME column ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? Btw: using `LIKE` with an expression that doesn't contain wildcards does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear.  The index is placed on ID column.  I'm using sql server 2008 r2.  Sorry about the like thing.  I suppose I could've done the = sign instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since `first_name` is not part of any index, there's no point in the database using an index - it will have to scan all of it, access the actual table row for each entry, and evaluate the `first_name` value there. Since it's accessing all the table's rows anyway, the optimizer just prefers to perform a full table scan, and save the (useless) index accesses.

If you want to use an index to speed up your query, you should create one that covers this column. E.g.:

```
CREATE INDEX table_a_first_name_ind ON table_a(first_name)
```